# What is the cause of sound produced by suction cups?

Tags: acoustics, vacuum

A partial vacuum is created when suction cups are pushed on to a smooth surface, and a distinct sound is produced when they are pulled apart. Why is this sound produced?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of this answer: Sound travels in the form of pressure waves. The partial vacuum is of extremely low pressure. When this low-pressure region is suddenly exposed to the high-pressure atmosphere, pressure waves will be produced and this results in a sound wave. The frequency and amplitude of the sound produced will depend on the actual conditions.

Comment: You mean what is that sound you hear when your mom kisses you on the cheek?

Comment: yes. i think both have the same cause